# Vue-component emitting

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my first Vue.js component, I try to emit event from it. But my browser doesnt see 'updateValue' method... Whats wrong?

```
<template>
        <div>
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                <li v-for="item in items">
                    <div class="nav-link" onclick="updateValue(1)">
                        {{ item.name }}
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            props: ['items'],
            methods: {
                updateValue: function (value){
                    this.$emit('change', value);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Use `@click` not `onclick`

Comment: thanks, problem solved! =)

Answer (score 3):

In Vue you should use `@click` or `v-on:click` instead of `onclick`.